# Default setting for "Build Action" and "Copy to Output Directory"?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I noticed when I'm making a new ASP.NET non-MVC2 Webapplication project. In the file properties for either .aspx or .cs files, there are 2 settings that I'm wondering what are defaults for. The reason I'm asking is because there's a couple of files I'm reusing from my last project and the settings were changed when I add the files into the project. For example all the aspx and .cs "Build Action" setting is set to "content" and all the "Copy to Output Directory" is set to "Do not copy"

Comment: O yes I forgot about the files Site.Master, Global.asax and Web.config, I'm pretty sure web.config don't need to compile but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe for Default.aspx the build Action shoud be Content and for Default.aspx.cs the build Action should be Compile.

Site.Master build action is Content but the Site.Master.cs is compile. Global.asax build action is Content but the Global.asax.cs is compile and finally web.config is content